# Remove Elements from JSON String

Tags: java, json, string

I have a JSON string as follows:

```
{
   "account": "1234",
   "type": "ar-type",
   "eventTypes": "Update",
   "objectClassName": "com.triype",
   "objectJson": "{\"Name\":\"pdpot\",\"traptype\":\"adpot",\"displayName\":\"pdpot",\"experimentName\":\"pdpotpie\",\"creationTime\":\"Mar 18, 2020 5:58:58 PM\",\"createdBy\":{\"userProfileOne\":\"s:pdx\",\"userProfileTwo\":\"sid\",\"domainId\":\"did:pdx-tod-64003\"},\"lastModifiedBy\":{\"userProfileArn\":\"s:pdx-tod-64003\"},\"createdBy\":{\"userProfileOne\":\"s:p\",\"userProfileTwo\":\"si\",\"domainId\":\"did:ppot\"}}}
}
```

I get this input as a string and before passing it as a string to a parser I need to perform some string filtering and remove all "userProfileOne", "userProfileTwo","domainId" and their keys, without compromising the JSON structure. I am currently writing this code in Java using gson and json.

Note: There are multiple occurences of UserProfileOne, UserProfileTwo and DomainID.

The required Output is as follows:

```
{
   "account": "1234",
   "type": "ar-type",
   "eventTypes": "Update",
   "objectClassName": "com.triype",
   "objectJson": "{\"Name\":\"pdpot\",\"traptype\":\"adpot",\"displayName\":\"pdpot",\"experimentName\":\"pdpotpie\",\"creationTime\":\"Mar 18, 2020 5:58:58 PM\"}}
}
```

Currently I am using substringBetween. But the operation does not work as intended.

Comment: Why the escape chars \ in the content of "objectJson"?

Comment: Please show the code you used so far, as wel as the exact issue that you are running into.

Comment: Probably because it's a string

Comment: Looks like whole JSON is not well-formed, for example a quote after `adpot` isn't escaped.
In this circumstances you can use regexp to cut unnecessary fragments 
`\\"(userProfileOne|userProfileTwo|domainId)\\"\s*:\s*\\"(.+?)\\"\s*,?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential approach is to deserialize the json into a java structure then filter this structure by set to null fields you don't want to be serialize.

By using framework like Jackson you can set this before serialization on the `ObjectMapper`

`mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)`. So all null values won't be serialized in the final json/result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best maintainable way would be to create a class structure corresponding to that json and map it to the class.
Use @JsonIgnore on the fields to be ignored and then map it back to JSON from the class structure.

Another approach, a bit complex to implement, is to go through each node in the json and remove that node if it's not required

You can also do it by string matching but I don't think that is a good approach.